# How do I access Django environment variables using `pipenv`?

Tags: python, django, pipenv

There are so many ways to add necessary secrets such as `SECRET_KEY` as environment variables for Django.

I'm wondering what really good ways there might be using `pipenv`?

I've been using `.env`, is this a professional enough way of doing it?

Comment: Please be more specfic about what are you trying to achieve exactly. What do you mean by  using `.env` ? What is the point of making SECRET_KEY a system environnement variable when you can simply import it anywhere in your app ?

Comment: Yes, using `.env` is perfectly normal, as long as you don't commit your production credentials in remote VCS. For production ready Django, I'd recommend using `cookiecutter-django`.